# Как убрать при обрезании строки (substr) знаки вопроса?

Tags: php

При обрезании строки (substr) вылазят знаки вопроса?

База и сайт в utf-8. При обрезании строки:

```
if( strlen( $text ) > $Doska->Config['short_echo_max_strlen'] ) $text = substr( $text, 0, $Doska->Config['short_echo_max_strlen'] )."..";
```

получается:

> и тянет игры до 2010 год�..

```
mb_strlen();
mb_substr();
```

тоже почему то не помогает!

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

Установите в начале скрипта внутреннюю кодировку скрипта командой

```
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
```

И используйте функции `mb_strlen()` и `mb_substr();` для работы с многобайтными строками https://secure.php.net/manual/ru/book.mbstring.php

Comment: можете подсказать?! я не очень в php силен!  mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8'); устанавливать перед if( strlen( $text ) > $Doska->Config['short_echo_max_strlen'] ) $text = substr( $text, 0, $Doska->Config['short_echo_max_strlen'] )."..";

Comment: Можно перед этим кодом отдельной строкой, если раньше вы не обрабатываете многобайтные строки. Можно и в самом начале скрипта.

Comment: увы вообще не отоброжает тогда страницу делаю так :       if( $Doska->Config['short_echo_allowhtml'] != "yes" ) $text = strip_tags( $text, "<br>" );
      mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
      if( mb_strlen( $text > $Doska->Config['short_echo_max_strlen'] ) $text = mb_substr( $text, 0, $Doska->Config['short_echo_max_substr'] )."..";

Comment: Скобку забыли при закрытии mb_strlen. Отладку скриптов делайте с включенным отображением всех ошибок и предупреждений.

Comment: теперь обрезаемый текст пропал вовсе остались только точки ..

Comment: А можно увидеть, что у вас в $text находится и чему равны $Doska->Config['short_echo_max_strlen'] и $Doska->Config['short_echo_max_substr']?

Comment: [ссылка]http://rghost.ru/8QbZ4vJXD[/ссылка] вот сам файлик у меня на dle движке это все дело

Comment: У вас тут чушь написана: `mb_substr( $text, 60, 'UTF-8' $Doska->Config['short_echo_max_substr'] )`. Исправляйте.

Comment: http://rghost.ru/6qqY6ftVy Вот извините не внимательный я

Answer (score 2):

в конце mb_substr, пропишите кодировку:

```
mb_substr($text, 0, [xx], 'UTF-8')
```

И всё будет нормально, без �.