# Проблема работы php скрипта с кириллицей (в .txt файле)

Tags: php, кодировка, файлы, функции, кириллица

Хочу сразу сказать что только учусь, по этому мог упустить из виду что-то простое=)

Стоит задача - создать функцию убирающую слова длиннее внесенного в нее значения.

На латиницу функция реагирует корректно, а вот с кириллическим шрифтом никак не могу разобраться.

Если скормить части функции, которая отвечает за подсчет, строку из текущего ".php" файла - все работает корректно, но при работе с заданным в параметре файлом".txt" она уже сбоит, удаляет некоторые слова которые короче лимита.
Рабочий файл обычный txt - кодировка 'UTF-8', пробовал определять кодировку функцией - она тоже говорит что 'UTF-8', кодировка файла со скриптом 'UTF-8'.
Код приведен ниже:

Спасибо за помощь)

```
function deleteWordsLongerX ($file, $maxLength) {
$result = "";//заранее задаю переменную(для избежания предупреждения)
if(!file_exists($file)) {//проверка файла
    echo "Файл не существует";
} elseif (!is_writable($file)) {
    echo "В файл нельзя произвести запись";
} else {//начинаю обработку файла
    $text = file_get_contents($file);//открытие
    $text = explode(' ', $text);//разделение на массив
    $count = count($text);//считаем количество элементов массива(слов)

    for ($i=0;$i<$count;$i++) {//Проходим по массиву
        if(mb_strlen($text[$i])<$maxLength+1) {/*В случае если слово из 
        массива короче максимально заданной длинны слова отправляем его в 
        результирующую строку, используется функция для мегабитных шрифтов.*/
            $result .= $text[$i] . ' ';
        }
    }
    file_put_contents ($file, $result);//записываем результат обратно в файл
    echo "Файл успешно отредактирован.";
}
```

Пример работы скрипта:
изначальный текст (звездочками отметил где скрипт не сработал)

`Это проверка на работу с кириллицей тест тест *привет* 
*Eto* proverka na rabotu s kirillicey test test privet`

Результат работы с параметром 8:
`Это проверка на работу с тест тест 
proverka na rabotu s test test privet`

П.с
Пробовал явно выставлять несколько вариантов кодировок для функции mb и в файле ставить mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');

Comment: Укажите в функциях `mb_` кодировку `UTF-8` или так сделайте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/444529/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%83%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8-substr-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b0/444534#444534

Answer (score 1):

Дело в том, что функция `mb_strlen` возвращает длину строки в байтах, для латиницы длина строки равна количеству символов, так как 1 символ занимает 1 байт, а для кириллицы - один символ занимает 2 байта. Поэтому вы получаете поведение, которого не ожидаете.

```
echo mb_strlen('ффф'); // 6
echo mb_strlen('fff'); // 3

echo mb_strlen('ффф','UTF-8'); // 3
echo mb_strlen('fff','UTF-8'); // 3
```

Попробуйте задать кодировку явно, и тогда проблем с кириллицей не будет:

```
mb_strlen($text[$i],'UTF-8');
```

Comment: Пробовал этот вариант одним из первых(

Comment: @Vlad, всё зависит от кодировки вашего `txt` файла. Если он сохранен с кодировкой `utf-8`, все работать будет.

Comment: Файл сохранен в utf-8 к сожалению не могу(или не умею) в комментарий скинуть скрин

Comment: @Vlad, и вы используете именно тот вариант, с явной передачей кодировки в функцию?

Comment: Да, с ним - уже нашел свой промах, нужно будет использовать preg_match вместо explode.

Answer (score 0):

Забыл учесть важный момент, разделитель работает только по пробелу, а там есть еще переносы строк - и получалось он слепливал некоторые слова - в следствии чего и удалял их как превышающие допустимый размер.
Всем большое спасибо за помощь=)

P.s
Насколько грамотным будет такое дополнение к коду при желании добавить ему универсальности?
$coding = mb_detect_encoding($file);
mb_strlen($text[$i], $coding);